# How do I assign an ID to SVG code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have an SVG code for a map. This code is part of the map

```
<circle opacity="0.33" fill="#913A3A" stroke="#CDC9C4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="273.5" cy="231.9" r="18.6"/>
```

I want to change its fill color on button click. I added the button code.

I am aware of the JavaScript code with it. However, when I assign an ID for this code and test it out like this

```
<Pathid = "path1" circle opacity="0.33" fill="#913A3A" stroke="#CDC9C4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="273.5" cy="231.9" r="18.6"/>
```

The circle disappears from the map. How can I deal with that?

This is the JavaScript that I used

```
$('#btn-test1').on("click", function() {
  $('#path1').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
});
```

Comment: <circle opacity="0.33" fill="#913A3A" stroke="#CDC9C4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="273.5" cy="231.9" r="18.6"/>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by assign an ID and test it out as you're providing some entirely different markup following that, what does that markup have to do with your question?

Comment: Have you tried: `<circle id="test1" opacity="0.33" fill="#913A3A" stroke="#CDC9C4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="273.5" cy="231.9" r="18.6"/>` ?

Comment: I tried <circle id="test1" , the circle did not disappear but the color doesn't change when I click on the button

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's simply impossible to give an SVG element an ID. I would probably use a canvas element for this anyways. Please tell me if I'm misinformed.

Comment: I didn't get what you are  saying. Then how can I change the color of the circle on a button click with my SVG code?

Comment: Could you please include all of the code so I can see the results of running it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it is my first time using stack overflow

Comment: You haven't added your JavaScript code here. Just giving me the HTML doesn't help much.

Comment: No problem, don't worry about it.

Comment: This is the circle code, it is part of a map <circle opacity="0.33" fill="#913A3A" stroke="#CDC9C4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="273.5" cy="231.9" r="18.6"/>
I added above the button code <button class="btn" id="btn-test1">Test 1</button> on the javascript I added $('#btn-test1').on("click", function() {
    $('#path1').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
}); and it  didn't work

Comment: this is the java script code $('#btn-test1').on("click", function() {
    $('#path1').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
});

Comment: If you make an edit to your original question and add this code in, I could run it more easily.

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/P6t2B/295/ , it is working with this example but when I tried it with my circle it doesn't work

Comment: This Fiddle appears to be using path elements, instead of circle or rect elements. Have you tried using path elements instead?

Comment: What do you mean by using path elements? Because I want specifically to change the color of that circle.

Comment: A path elements allows you to define a "path" that on which a line will be drawn, in order to draw a very specific shape.

Comment: Eh, it would sort of be over complicating things, so I won't explain it unless we can't find another solution. Do you have anything against using canvas instead of SVG?

Comment: What is canvas? I already drew my whole map using illustrator and got the SVG code from illustrator...

Comment: Simply.. I want to assign an ID to my circle so I can have this ID and play with it in the java script.. is that possible or not?

Comment: If it is possible, I never knew, and I don't know why this doesn't work. Sorry I can't be of any other help.

Comment: Thank you so much  for trying

Comment: Of course! Sorry I couldn't give a great answer. If you can't find a solution, try using canvas, and ask me if you aren't familiar with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

In your example,

- you've replaced the `<circle>` element with a `<pathid>` custom element. You probably meant `<circle Pathid = "path1".../>`
- but the spaces around that `=` are going to be a problem, so `<circle Pathid="path1".../>`
- but you're trying to give the `<circle>` an `id`, not some custom `Pathid` attribute, so

**`<circle id="path1".../>`**

When changing just one CSS class with jQuery, you can be a little less verbose with the syntax `.css("property","value")` - in this case, that's

**`$('#path1').css("fill","#ff0000");`**

Here it is all put together. Don't worry about my `<svg>`'s `viewbox` or its width - that's just some basic sizing for the demo, and won't be relevant when the circle is in your `<svg>`.

```js
$('#btn-test1').on("click", function() {
  $('#path1').css("fill", "#ff0000");
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="btn-test1" viewbox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle id="path1" opacity="0.33" fill="#913A3A" stroke="#CDC9C4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="20" cy="20" r="18.6" />
</svg>
```